# TextMate 2 wrong encoding

Tags: encoding, textmate

okay, so I was clumsy and chose the wrong encoding opening a document with unknown encoding in TextMate 2 (v. 2.0-beta.8.5).
Is there a simple way of reselecting the encoding?
I read there was such an alternative in TextMate 1 (File -> Re-open with encoding), but I can't find one in this version.
And to clarify, I don't wish to change the encoding of the document, only the encoding TextMate uses to view the document.

edit; I opened the document on my Windows PC in Notepad2 (where it looks okay) to check the encoding. The encoding is UTF-16 LE

Comment: What would happen if you made a new document and then copy pasted the content there? Would the new content be garbled from bad encoding of the old file?

Comment: Yes @Michael the new document with the pasted content looks exactly the same as the original.